# Prevent some users modifying a Neo4J node

Tags: java, security, neo4j

In my Neo4J database, I want to prevent particular users modifying nodes.  I would like to allow any user to be a 'guest' and view data and certain users to be admins and view and edit as much data as they like.

This needs to be part of the neo4j server, I would rather not implement a webservice over neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to perform what you are looking for by using [`SecurityRule`](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-server/stable/apidocs/org/neo4j/server/rest/security/SecurityRule.html). There's a better description of what this does [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules).

Basically what this allows you to do is set up HTTP authorization on specific URL's. What you could do is check that URL to see what node it's attempt to access and if the user is not allowed to mutate it, deny the request.

Comment: Many thanks.  It looks like I could fail everything but GET requests unless the they have HTTP authentication which would be OK for now.  One more thing... Do you know how I could get a reference to the database from the rule?

Comment: `SecurityRule` has a `DEFAULT_DATABASE_PATH` which links to the database, but it does not have access to the GraphDatabaseService. //UPDATE: I just did a test and it looks like no, you do not have access to the `@Context`, so it's up to you to gain access to the actual graph database.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Neo4j Server slave in read-only mode, as a mirror of the read/write master. Or you can implement node-level permissions, like you would in a RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might be the way.  I am looking to run on Heroku or something similar, so this would double the cost of my data.  Is there any doco for node level permissions?